how to optimize SQL query with multiple JSONB contains conditions?
i am working on a PostgreSQL database where i need to filter rows based on multiple conditions in a JSONB column. the column attributes stores data like this
{
"color": "red",
"size": "large",
"shape": "circle"
}


i want to find rows where,
color is "red" and size is "large"
currently i use the @> operator like this
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE attributes @> '{"color": "red"}'
  AND attributes @> '{"size": "large"}';


this works but i suspect it is not the most efficient way since i will be adding more conditions later.
would creating a GIN index help with performance and if so how should i create it?

Both the default as well as jsonb_path_ops support the containment @> operator. Create the index, vacuum analyze the table and run some tests. How much of a boost you'll get depends various factors, like the table size, value size and complexity, other parts of the query etc. With jsonpath expressions you can squeeze all these conditions into a single @? operation.

Try with … WHERE attributes @> '{"color": "red", "size": "large"}'; instead

@Bergi Good point. I added a test showing this does run faster, with and without an index.

Both the default GIN operator class jsonb_ops as well as jsonb_path_ops support the containment @> operator. Create the index, vacuum analyze the table:
create index on products using gin(attributes);
vacuum analyze products;

Then run some test with explain analyze verbose or even proper benchmarks with pgbench.
How much of a boost you'll get depends various factors, like the table size, value size and complexity, other parts of the query etc. Tables in the lower thousands may not even use the index because scanning them whole might be so cheap that Postgres won't bother looking for shortcuts.
With jsonpath expressions you can squeeze all these conditions and more, into a single @? or @@ operation:
demo at db<>fiddle
create index on products using gin(attributes jsonb_path_ops);
vacuum analyze products;

explain analyze verbose
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE attributes @@ '$.color=="red" 
                     && 
                     $.size=="large"';




QUERY PLAN




Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products  (cost=25.48..207.32 rows=707 width=105) (actual time=1.551..2.941 rows=621 loops=1)


  Output: id, attributes


  Recheck Cond: (products.attributes @@ '($."color" == "red" && $."size" == "large")'::jsonpath)


  Heap Blocks: exact=168


  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_attributes_idx  (cost=0.00..25.30 rows=707 width=0) (actual time=1.266..1.267 rows=621 loops=1)


        Index Cond: (products.attributes @@ '($."color" == "red" && $."size" == "large")'::jsonpath)


Planning Time: 1.201 ms


Execution Time: 3.283 ms



If you don't need all the additional features of JSONPath, @Bergi's idea to merge the conditions can speed up your query a bit. In a test with some 300k somewhat randomised rows, it reliably faster with and without an index. Here's without:



variant
avg
min
max
sum
stddev
mode




bergi_merged
00:00:00.101224
00:00:00.088824
00:00:00.109947
00:00:04.048966
00:00:00.004158
00:00:00.088824


op_version
00:00:00.104604
00:00:00.093529
00:00:00.113067
00:00:04.184155
00:00:00.004641
00:00:00.093529


jsonpath
00:00:00.154695
00:00:00.140819
00:00:00.16828
00:00:06.187784
00:00:00.006629
00:00:00.140819



And here's with



variant
avg
min
max
sum
stddev
mode




bergi_merged
00:00:00.016154
00:00:00.013517
00:00:00.017935
00:00:00.646145
00:00:00.000994
00:00:00.016901


op_version
00:00:00.018822
00:00:00.013958
00:00:00.09185
00:00:00.752897
00:00:00.01193
00:00:00.013958


jsonpath
00:00:00.019326
00:00:00.016472
00:00:00.023866
00:00:00.773032
00:00:00.001564
00:00:00.016472



